Importing an excel range containing formulas over a large number of files
I'm trying to pull a specific range (I20:I21) from a large number of excel files (289) and combine them into a data frame.
These cells contain formulas. I saw in some threads that using "read_excel" would work but it's not solving the issue.
If I make a loop or a function, it only return about 10 of file values properly, everything else is filled with NAs and I don't understand why. If the use of a function is the problem I don't see why some files would load properly and others not (it's the same file with different values).
Please let me know what you think could work, below is the code I used:
files <- list.files('.', pattern = '*.xlsx', recursive = TRUE)
estimation_list <- lapply(files, 
              function(x) {readxl::read_excel(x, sheet = "Main tab", range = "I20:I21", col_names = FALSE)}) %>% 
  bind_cols %>% 
  t %>% 
  data.frame

colnames(estimation_list) <- c('lower', 'upper bound')
estimation_list$project <- files
write.xlsx(estimation_list,"updated_estimates.xlsx")

Here is what I get
enter image description here
Edit based on @nkalvi's comment. The cells being pulled are referring to calculations based on others cells which are all pulling from another sheet "input"
This is the formula for cell I20 that I'm trying to pull. I3 is calling from another sheet.
=IF($C$21<1,$C$21*$I3,$I3)*I13+IF($C$21<1,$C$21*$I$3,$I$3)

My guess is that this is the problem?

Hey, could you please show sample formulas behind at least couple of the N/As? (of course obfuscating any confidential info.) Wondering whether some could be referring to other sheets.

Hey Nkalvi, I'll share a little more, I don't think there is anything confidential but it is definitely referring to other sheets.

Thanks Léa, referring to another sheet within the same workbook may not be a problem, but when referring to external workbooks, "When the source workbook is not open, the workbook link in the destination workbook includes the entire path. For example:
=SUM('C:\Reports[Budget.xlsx]Annual'!C10:C25)". So, please check such references to make sure they include the entire path.

If you haven't already, please take a look at this: Read excel file with formulas in cells into R - Stack Overflow

You may want to look at Import data from a folder with multiple files (Power Query) - Microsoft Support as well, if you have Windows version of Microsoft 365. That is if the 'R` route doesn't work well.

Thank nkalvi, I these other articles, I'll try them out and see if it works. Thanks for your help! I know it's tough to address without seeing the actual excel file

I'm familiar with Power Query, not with 'R' (yet ;) Good luck!
